# Is there a way to retrieve Heroku logs over HTTP?

Tags: heroku

I'd like to access Heroku logs for an app without using the command line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently No.  If you're looking to use this from within a Ruby based app you can embed the heroku gem and use it programatically which might help.

Comment: unfortunatelly, it's for a node.js app

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. It's a simple REST API. There aren't any JavaScript wrappers for the API, but you can use these as reference implementations, or use them directly:

- https://github.com/heroku/heroku.jar
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py